# Making a DFH functions Header file

Tags: class, reusability, turbo-c++

**Edit:** This question is not off-topic as it describes an issue in data file handling with Turbo C++.

First of all, Turbo C++ is because of my school. Don't comment telling me to stop using it, I'm forced.

**Introduction:** I'm trying to build a DFH library, so I made all these functions to write, read, insert, delete, modify, etc.
I used stings to make the functions work for any filename passed to them.

What I understand (self-learned) from the whole making a class and then passing it's object in the `read_stream.read((char*)& Object_1, sizeof(Object_1));` form to read the file, that you wrote using the same object is that: **the class works as sort of a template to print data onto the file**.

**Question:** I want to use them with different objects of different classes, so the class whose object these DFH functions use for performing the desired task should be sort of like a template.

I was thinking on doing something with templates or abstract class and inheritance but I'm a beginner so I need someone to point me in the right direction!

**To clear up:** I want to use the same functions by just including this source file into other programs containing different classes.

**Example Code**

```
class Data {
      int user_id;
public:
void enter() {   //Input Function
    cout<<"\nID: ";
    cin>>user_id;
};

void write(char* file_1) {   //File Write Function
    clrscr();
    Data Object_1;
    char ch;
    int records_read =0;

    ofstream fout;
    fout.open(file_1, ios::binary|ios::noreplace);
    do {
        records_read++;
        Object_1.enter(records_read);
        fout.write((char*)& Object_1, sizeof(Object_1));
        cout<<"\nDo you want to continue? Y/N  -  ";
        cin>>ch;
    } while((ch=='y')||(ch=='Y'));
    cout<<"\nWrite Successful!";
    fout.close();
}
```

How do I make the function write() work with any other class, without having to explicitly change the statement `Data Object_1;` ?

Comment: you did not specify what functionality you want to achieve ... perhaps adding desired sample input and output would be better. You can group the whole record of your data into single `class`. Also I would expect that partial `write()` function would be member of your class too ... and used in your main write function.